# Conteudo da div se ajustando com seu tamanho?

Tags: css

Tenho uma div que controla o tamanho maximo que uma imagem pode ter. Gostaria que a imagem se ajustasse ao tamanho da div, sem que cortasse parte dela (como acontece no `overflow: hide`).

Usei o `overflow:hide` para a imagem nao ultrapassar o limite da div.

HTML:

```
<div id="controlImg">
    <img src="img/arroz.jpg">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#controlImg{
max-width: 400px;
max-height: 500px;
border: 1px solid green;}

#controlImg img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

No `overflow: auto`, cria-se uma barra de scroll ao inves de cortar a imagem, mas gostaria mesmo é que ela se adaptasse ao tamanho da div pai (controlImg)

Na imagem, inseri `width:100%` e `height:100%`, mas a imagem nao obedeceu, como mostra na imagem:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: max-width: 100%;
max-height: 100%;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pode usar um `width: 100%` para a imagem ocupar toda a largura do elemento pai:

```css
#controlImg {
    max-width: 400px;
    max-height: 500px;
    border: 1px solid red
}

#controlImg img {
  width: 100%
}
```

```html
<div id="controlImg">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/900">
</div>
```

Ou utilizando como `background` do elemento:

```css
div {
  width: 500px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid red
}

.rice {
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Jgo0.jpg); 
  background-size: 100% 100%
}
```

```html
<div class='rice'></div>
```

Comment: Renan obrigado pela resposta. Eu fiz assim, e ainda adicionei o height 100%, mas nao funcionou, como na imagem que inseri

Comment: Se for aplicar o tamanho na altura (ao invés da largura), seu elemento pai deverá ter um tamanho definido (um `height` e não `max-height`). E nesse caso não vai adiantar usar `height` e `width` juntos com 100%, a imagem não vai "se expandir" e ocupar todo o elemento, para isso você teria que usar a imagem como `background` do elemento.

Comment: @WesLipe editei.

Comment: Funcionou, mas infelizmente nao se encaixa no que eu preciso, pois a imagem (no caso do arroz) virá do banco, entao sera uma imagem por produto, nao posso setar no css uma padrao

Comment: O meu erro era que eu estava inserindo o max height e width na div, ao inves da imagem.

Ao informar pra imagem que o maximo de altura e largura que ela deve ter é 100% em relação ao pai, a imagem se comportou bem.

O codigo:
#modalProduto #controlImg{
 border: 1px solid green;
}

#controlImg img {
 /* largura e altura maxima de 100% da div pai */
 max-width: 100%;
 max-height: 100%; 
}